# Clarification of an alloca() bug

Tags: c, memory-management

I read [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) in the *man-pages*:

> On many systems alloca() cannot be used inside the list of arguments
>   of a function call, because the stack space reserved by alloca() would
>   appear on the stack in the middle of the space for the function
>   arguments.

I believe that `alloca()` has *approximately* this implementation:

```
void *alloca(size_t size)
{
    <sp> -= size; /* the initial value of the stack pointer*/
    return <sp>;
}
```

I would be glad to understand the implications of that bug.

1. What problems does it involve? Overwriting of the arguments? Also
2. I do not understand why you would use the function as a
   callback putting it as an argument of another function.

Comment: The problem isn't about using it as a callback, just calling `alloca` in a parameter list: `func(alloca(42))`.

Comment: whereas you could put a call to malloc in the parameter list: `func(malloc(42))`.

Comment: @bruceg But then you have a memory leak.

Comment: @FredK true... presumably you could call free in func.  Who doesn't love functions with side effects.